# Convert dataframe column from int to exponential

Tags: python, pandas, integer, exp

What is the best approach to convert the column "price" to be in exponential form e.g laptop-->1.0E4?

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],
            'price': [10000, 100000, 1000000, 45000, 2000]
            }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df

Output:
  product_name    price
0       laptop    10000
1      printer   100000
2       tablet  1000000
3         desk    45000
4        chair     2000
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of formatting.  You can set the default float format up front, and cast your int to float and print.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.1E}'.format)
data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair'],
            'price': [10000, 100000, 1000000, 45000, 2000]
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['price'] = df['price'].astype(float)

print(df)
```

Output

```
  product_name   price
0       laptop 1.0E+04
1      printer 1.0E+05
2       tablet 1.0E+06
3         desk 4.5E+04
4        chair 2.0E+03
```

Comment: When I plot the data the numbers do not show up in the exponential form in the legends. This is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-int-to-exponential/)
and made it as a function like this

```
def int2exp(n: int):
    return "{:e}".format(n)
```